# Is there a way to speed up SUM() function in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm want to know if there's any way of speeding up this query,

```sql
SELECT
     SUM(quantity) as quantity
    ,productId
FROM krakoweats.orderproducts
GROUP BY productId
ORDER BY quantity DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

The table looks like this

```
Columns:
orderId int(11) PK 
productId int(11) PK 
quantity int(11) 
unityPrice double 
createdAt datetime 
updatedAt datetime
```

I want to fetch the top 3 selling products. The table has about 11 milion records and it takes about 9 seconds to run, is there a way to speed it up? I'm working with mariadb.

EDIT:

I have indexes like this

```
+---------------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name                           | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+---------------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| orderproducts |          0 | order_products_order_id_product_id |            1 | orderId     | A         |       55747 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| orderproducts |          0 | order_products_order_id_product_id |            2 | productId   | A         |      579777 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| orderproducts |          1 | order_products_product_id          |            1 | productId   | A         |       31254 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+---------------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+-------
```

Comment: Indexing is where performance starts. Grouping by ProductId will require sorting on that column, this should be indexed or the leading left column of the primary key. Have you checked the `explain` plan?

Comment: create another table named TopSellingProducts and run a job to insert data in this table on timeframe of 10-20 minutes. use this table in your dashboard to show top selling products.

Answer (score 1):

```
INDEX(product_id, order_id)  -- in this order
```

Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

I think your setup will do two sorts; and mine, only one.

There is no way to avoid a full table scan.  However, if you had a [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) , a query against such would probably run a lot faster.

Answer (score -1):

Try to:
#1 create a separate index for productId field.
#2 increase cache for queries settings in the config file of MariaDB

Comment: He seems to have a separate index for `product_id`.